# Run .NET Web Application in subfolder of another .NET MVC application with IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm not sure the other questions I've seen pertained to this scenario, so this may be a duplicate.

I am running a site called http://mysite.mydomain.com/. We are transitioning to a new version in a piecemeal format, and I want all the new transactions to live in a different MVC application. I'd like to do the following:

http://mysite.mydomain.com/v2/ - New application

Is this possible to simply point a subfolder to the new application. Then in my old web site, I can simply redirect to the subfolder and hit the new application?

This is utilizing IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  You can even use WebDeploy to deploy both the root and child web application.  Just set these MSBuild properties:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DeployIisAppPath>Default Web Site</DeployIisAppPath>
  <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The following blog post details this setup.

http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/03/03/simple-service-versioning-with-webdeploy/

Comment: These would be two completely separate web applications. Is this possible via virtual directories? Or is this the means to doing it?

Comment: Yes, this will work with separate applications in different solutions as well.

Comment: Just deploy the "v2" site as a virtual application under your current site in IIS. Be careful of Web.config inheritance, though, as virtual apps inherit the Web.config settings of the site they're in. You can disable inheritance for specific sections in your Web.config by adding the `inheritInChildApplications="false"` attribute to the relevant sections.